# How to access an object by referencing its value from a string in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

what exactly I want to do is, I have a file say `permissions.js` with contents:

**Permissions.js**

```
module..exports = {
  Student: {
    Read: true,
    Service: "StudentService",
    Teach: false
  },
  Teacher: {
    Read: false,
    Service: "TeacherService",
    Teach: true
  }
}
```

and another file `functions.js`:

**functions.js**

```
// functions.js
module.exports = {
  StudentService: {
    someFunc1: function() {...},
    someFunc2: function() {...},
    someFunc3: function() {...}
  },
  TeacherService: {
    someFunc1: function() {...},
    someFunc2: function() {...},
    someFunc3: function() {...}
  }
}
```

and importing both the files in `school.js`:

**school.js**

```
// school.js
import functions from "./path-to/functions.js";
import { Student, Teacher } from "./path-to/permissions.js";

// Making it very simple
let service = Student.Service; // service = "StudentService"
service.someFunc1() // returns someFunc1 is not a function
```

So what I want to do is use the `service` variable as a reference for the `StudentService` in `functions.js`. Cannot use require.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't isn't specific to react-native at all, just modern JS modules. This will work:

```
import * as functions from "./path-to/functions.js"
import { Student } from "./path-to/permissions.js"

let service = Student.Service;
functions[service].someFunc1
```

A better approach though would be this:

**perissions.js**

```
import { StudentService, TeacherService } from "./path-to/functions.js";

module.exports = {
  Student: {
    Read: true,
    Service: StudentService,
    Teach: false
  },
  Teacher: {
    Read: false,
    Service: TeacherService,
    Teach: true
  }
}
```

And then you never have to mess about referencing things with strings.